# pasar una suma que se hace de JavaScript a HTML

Tags: javascript, html

soy novato en todo esto, y tengo una pregunta, como le puedo hacer para pasar una suma que se hace desde JavaScript a una tabla que hice en HTML, muchas gracias

la suma seria

`suma = dato 1 + dato 2`

cuando lo pongo en `console.log(suma);` si me hace la suma correcta mente, solo que necesito poner ese dato en una tabla de HTMl

Comment: Segun lo planteado, puedes usar: [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola Tomas para esto solo tienes que encontrar la casilla de resultado en tu tabla. Si tienes acceso a esta estiqueta en tu html tu puedes ponerle un id o si ya tiene id lo puedes user en javascript con esto :

```
let suma = dato1 + dato2;

document.getElementById('miId').textContent = suma;
```

Te hice une codePen : https://codepen.io/Tonioverzeworld/pen/WNRLvXe?editors=1010

Espero que esto conteste tu pregunta

Comment: Amigo, muchisimas gracias de verdad

Comment: No es necesario hacerlo en codePen, stackoverflow tiene opcion para hacer codigo ejecutable y tu codigo, te recomiendo leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que quieres mostrar el valor en un input y siguiendo tu pregunta:

```
suma = dato1 + dato2;

document.getElementById("resultado").value = suma; 

//Acá lo muestras
<input type="text" id="resultado"/>
```